# make_node requires 4D tensor of kernels

Tags: python, numpy, theano, keras

I have trained cnn model and saved parameters in five files,but when I use these params to test photos ,I meet a question like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSVJV.png)

the code of load_data is:

```
def load_data(pag_name):``
k = 0
for filename in os.listdir(pag_name):
    if (filename != '.DS_Store'):
        k = k + 1
num = k
# test_per = k*4
print k

i = 0
j = 0
label = 0

train_set = numpy.empty((num, 1, 56, 56))
while (j < 1):
    for filename in os.listdir(pag_name):
        if (filename != '.DS_Store'):
            filename = pag_name+ '/' + filename
            image = Image.open(filename)
            #print image.size
            #print image
            img_ndarray = numpy.asarray(image, dtype='float64') / 256
            img_ndarray = numpy.asarray([img_ndarray])
                    # train_set[i] = numpy.ndarray.flatten(img_ndarray)
            train_set[i] = img_ndarray
            #print train_set.shape
                    # print filename1
                    # print 'label:', label
                    # print 'i:',i
            i = i + 1
    j = j + 1

def shared_dataset(data_x, borrow=True):
    shared_x = theano.shared(numpy.asarray(data_x,
                                           dtype=theano.config.floatX),
                             borrow=borrow)
    return shared_x

train_set = shared_dataset(train_set)
print train_set.get_value(borrow=True).shape
return train_set
```

and the code of use_CNN is :

```
def use_CNN(pag_name,nkerns=[20,40,60]):
data = load_data(pag_name)
data_num = data.get_value(borrow=True).shape[0]
layer0_params,layer01_params,layer1_params,layer2_params,layer3_params = load_params()
x = T.matrix('x')

layer0_input = x.reshape((data_num,1,56,56))
layer0 = LeNetConvPoolLayer(
    input=layer0_input,
    params_W = layer0_params[0],
    params_b = layer0_params[1],
    image_shape=(data_num, 1, 56, 56),
    filter_shape=(nkerns[0], 1, 5,5),
    poolsize=(2, 2)`
)
```

I haven't meet this problem ,and I don't know where and how I change my code.

Comment: could you give your `LeNetConvPoolLayer`class  code?

Comment: thank you. I have solved this problem.Because I save W and b in one file.But when I load params. Here are some problems.

Comment: the code of LeNetConvPoolLayer is:

Comment: It's my first time to use it, so I don't know how to paste my code.. It's too long, you can give me your email,I send my code to you.

Comment: oh, it's okay, if your code has run correctly, you don't have to show me your code. But, for the future viewer, it's better if you answer your own question by explaining how you solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the result of this error is the params are not 4D, the params I load is 3D, like my W and b is (20,1,5,5),but I load (1,5,5),so I meet this problem.